# Setting Column Width in Partial View within Bootstrap Navbar

Tags: asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, razor

I have a partial view (btn-group) within my bootstrap navbar that displays messages from my MessageController. I'd like this partial view to occupy the remaining space in my navbar. Right now the btn-group partial view changes width based upon the message length passed into the button, as below:

[Navbar with partial btn-group view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dGX17.png)

As you can imagine, this causes issues when there is a long message body, as below:

[Navbar with partial btn-group view, long message body](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dvkV7.png)

How do I make the partial view btn-group occupy the remaining navbar space? I have attempted many different code changes on my own, but I have had no luck so far.

Here is my partial view:

```
@using MyProject.UI.Helpers
@model IEnumerable<MyProject.Models.MessageModel>

<li class="btn-group">
    <a href="@Url.Action("Index", "Message")" class="btn btn-default">
        <span class="badge">@Html.Action("NumberOfMessages", "Message")</span> @Html.Action("MostRecentMessage", "Message")
    </a>
    <a class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down"></span>
    </a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
        @{var count = 0;}
        @foreach (var item in Model)
        {
            count = count + 1;
            <li>@Html.MenuItem(item.Subject + ": " + item.Body, "Index", "Message")</li>
        }
        @if (count == 5)
        {
            <li>@Html.MenuItem("...", "Index", "Message")</li>
        }
    </ul>
</li>
```

Here is the navbar code (the partial view is called in the     @Html.Action("NavbarMessages", "Message") list item):

```
@using MyProject.UI.Helpers

<div class="navbar navbar-fixed-top navbar-default">

    <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-responsive-collapse">
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="/">
            <div class="logo">
                <img src="~/Content/myapp-logo.png" height="23" />
                My Application
            </div>
        </a>
    </div>

    <div class="navbar-collapse collapse navbar-responsive-collapse">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            @Html.MenuItem("Home", "Home", "Home")
            <li class="dropdown">
                <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Applications <b class="caret"></b></a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                    <li class="dropdown-header">Setup</li>
                    @Html.MenuItem("SomeApp", "SomeApp", "Applications")
                    <li class="divider"></li>
                    <li class="dropdown-header">Apps</li>
                    @Html.MenuItem("App", "App", "Applications")
                    @Html.MenuItem("App", "App", "Applications")
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li class="dropdown">
                <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">System <b class="caret"></b></a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                    <li class="dropdown-header">Security</li>
                    <li class="divider"></li>
                    @Html.MenuItem("Users", "UsersStuff", "Users")
                    @Html.MenuItem("Roles", "RolesStuff", "SecurityRoles")
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li>@Html.Action("NavbarMessages", "Message")</li>
        </ul>
        @if (HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                <li class="dropdown">
                    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">@HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name <b class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></b></a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                        @Html.MenuItem("Change Password", "ChangePassword", "Security")
                        @Html.MenuItem("Logout", "Logout", "Security")
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        }
    </div>

</div>
```

I've edited my controller to only display 75 characters of the most recent message as a temporary solution. I'd still like to make this btn-group size occupy the empty navbar space if possible.

Thanks in advance for your help. Please let me know if you need anything else.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up making a navbar-form and passing the btn-group in to the form directly. I used css to make the width of the message btn-group static as follows:

Changed the partial view from

```
<li class="btn-group">
...
</li>
```

to

```
<div class="btn-group">
...
</div>
```

**And in the navbar code replaced**

```
<li>@Html.Action("NavbarMessages", "Message")</li>
```

in the above with

```
</ul>
<form class="navbar-form navbar-left">
@Html.Action("NavbarMessages", "Message")
</form>
```

The very simple css:

```
.truncate-message {
    text-align: left;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    overflow: hidden;
    white-space: nowrap;
    width: 500px;
}
```

I hope this helps!